# Rails s not working on MacOSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-mavericks

.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-rails-1.1.4/lib/compass-rails.rb:29:in `load_rails': undefined method`initialize!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0):

Stupid Mavericks MacOSX update!

Try

```
  rvm cleanup all
  rvm get stable
  rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p429
```

And Rails should be working again.